# Alternatives to ggtern?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

Since ggtern doesn't seem to get maintained anymore*, are there any alternatives to produce ternary diagrams with ggplot2?

*the current Version of ggtern (3.3.0) was released over a year ago, and it breaks ggplot2 Version 3.3.0 and up. Since there were a lot of changes from the previous ggplot2 versions, the only workaround (that I know of...) is to use an older Version of ggplot2 (i.e. Version 3.2.1)

Comment: Can you show a small example of breaking code please, as the [cran page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtern/index.html) would suggest that it depends on ggplot2 version >= 3.3.0 hence it *should* work)

Comment: Any plot you try to make using ggplot2 *after* loading ggtern is shown without axis and axis label, etc.

Comment: seems to be an issue https://github.com/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues . Seems as if it needs some rewrite but It doesn't look like it is being actively maintained. You could have a go at a fix?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not savy enough to fix this, I was (or am) merely a user of the package